# "Template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template"

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, clang, variadic-templates

```
template<typename... TArgs> struct List { };
template<template<typename...> class> struct ListHelper;
template<typename T, typename... TArgs> struct ListHelper<List<T, TArgs...>> { };
                                                          ^
   /*Error: Template argument for template template parameter 
             must be a class template or type alias template*/
```

What's wrong? I'm using clang++ SVN.

Comment: What's the template instantiation that shows the error, or does the template already fail by inclusion?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No instantiations. This is literally all the code in the program (except `int main() { return 0; }`)

Comment: I love this error message: 1 in 3 words is "template."

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have a template template parameter. You must pass a template as its argument. You instead pass a template instantiation as its argument - which is a concrete class, not a template (all its parameters are bound).

Consider:

```
template <template<typename> typename X>
class WantsTemplate {};

template <typename>
class ATemplate {};

WantsTemplate<ATemplate> wt1;  // OK
WantsTemplate<ATemplate<int> > wt2;  // not OK
```

Answer (score 2):

A template template parameter expects the template, not an instantiation of it. This:

```
template<typename T, typename... TArgs> struct ListHelper<List> { };
//                               only the template itself ^^^^
```

If you want to pass `List<T,TArgs...>`, which is a class, you'd need

```
template<typename T> struct ListHelper;
```